# Avoid oom-killer by limiting simultaneous users

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm trying to avoid a situation where I'm running out of ram resulting in the server locking up (oom-killer).

To achieve this I'm trying to update my Amazon Linux AMI instance to limit the number of simultaneous connections.

I have Apache 2.4 and following [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-apache-memory-tuning/), added the following to my httpd.conf:

```
MaxRequestWorkers = 112
ServerLimit = 112
```

However this results in the following warning on httpd restart:

> "MaxRequestWorkers takes one argument, Maximum number of children
>   alive at the same time"

Comment: nginx use significantly less ram than apache, nginx can easily handle 5,000 connections with less ram than it takes apache to handle 10 connections >.> you could try switching to nginx and see if that helps. - https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215945987-Web-server-performance-comparison

Answer (score 16):

The tutorial you followed has a pretty blatant error. Apache directives *do not* have an `=` character between the directive name and value.

The directives should read:

```
MaxRequestWorkers 112
ServerLimit 112
```

Keep in mind that this isn't likely to help all that much. The first thing you should do is switch to the event MPM (and php-fpm for PHP usage). If you are still using the 25 year old prefork MPM you are sacrificing a lot of performance and memory for little good reason. Just making this switch is likely to reduce your OOM issues while increasing performance dramatically.